# Pulling down data into a collectionView only when user is scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

have a collectionView that potentially loads a ton of cells depending on the data.  Currently my architecture is `viewDidLoad` (get first 25 from dataSource), then in `willDisplayCell` (get rest of datasource in sets of 25 until I hit a rate limit).  The problem is that it appears that its pulling down all the data at once.  I would like to not pull down more data for the cells unless the user is scrolling (i.e. unless those cells are necessary to be displayed).  How can I do this?

I know that I need to work with the `cell` and `indexPath` inside `willDisplayCell` but I can't quite piece it together?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getFirstPinsAndImages()

    }

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            if maxExceeded == false {
            getRestOfPinsAndImages()
            }



    }
```

Comment: `UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView` - you should be able to display the first 25 then use the [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:) methods to determine when you are scrolled to the bottom of your collection view and then load some more data.

Comment: Thanks @Wezly that may work as well but I was able to improve performance with my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was limit the data call to only when the `indexPath.row` of `willDisplayCell` (i.e. the row that is about to be displayed) was greater than the number of items in section (cells loaded) less some arbitrary number (to give a buffer for loading time):

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row > (self.collectionView(collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 10) {
            if maxExceeded == false {
                getRestOfPinsAndImages()
            }
        }
    }
```